# CSS Menu with strange order

Tags: css, list, menubar

I have a question about a little strange css menu. What i need:

- Three levels
- First level must be horizontal
- Second level must be on top of the first and in vertical
- Thire level must be bottom to the first on and in horizontal

It should looks like that (**forgott the forth level**):

```
     ...
     B.1.2
     B.1.1

A    B    C    D    E    ...

     B.2.1    B.2.2   ....

     B.3.1
     B.3.2
     ...
```

Do you have any ideas how to build a cross browser menu for that?

Comment: Does hovering on B show B1 and B2? Or is B2 a child of B1? (in which case the numbering is off)

Comment: I dont need hovering . i will deal with active classes. so for e.g. the second level should be shown complete if it is active. if the third level is active the second should be also shown. a bit crazy ;)

Answer (score 0):

I gave it a try in CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/c8tKC/6/

As you can see there is a problem to reach the third level with :hover selectors. You might want to toggle the display attribute using the onClick event.

Comment: Looks also fine but i have also browser issues for e.g. in IE 7, 8 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I did in the past minutes: http://jsfiddle.net/DUfUn/1/

It is pretty bad though, as two values depend on the count of items in the first submenu. This would have to be dynamically generated. But not impossible, if you fill the menu with a PHP script anyway. I commented the corresponding values.

Maybe this works as a basis and someone can extend it so that it becomes more dynamic.

Comment: Looks great .. but i've a problem with crossbrowser issue .. in IE 7, 8, 9 etc. the position is broken. i must also support mac browsers. so do i need browserhacks or could it be done without hacks? thx!

Comment: As said, this is just a rough example of how it might work. I'm currently working with Linux, so I can't test it in IE right now. But maybe you can fix it on your own, taking the code as a basis. Give it a try :-)